# Failing Kubernetes API health check

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver

I am checking the health of the Kubernetes API server over http using curl to https://127.0.0.1:8001/healthz/poststarthook/extensions/third-party-resources and it's failing with the following message:

```
"/apis",

"/apis/",

"/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io",

"/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1",

"/version"
```

other health checks are fine as they're reporting back as "ok"
I have tried some suggestions online checking versions of the client/server and it appears to be ok. I'm not sure what this output really means.

Comment: That response indicates that the api endpoint doesn't exist. Do you see it in the full output of the above command? If it exists, it should be there. Not every kubernetes distribution comes with it out of the box (ex. minikube).

Comment: That was the full output. How do I know that the endpoint doesn't exist instead of it being unresponsive? Sorry I am troubleshooting this but I am not familiar with the api

Comment: I ran "kubectl get" for "apiextension.k8s.io" and it return that it doesn't have a resource type. I'm guessing that's how you know as well?

Comment: What is your kubernetes version? How did you install it? What is your infrastructure?